# Google Analytics: can I combine trackEvent and trackPageView into a single call?

Tags: google-analytics

I am combining Google Analytics' _trackEvent and _trackPageview into a single call, like the following:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-20822178-2']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'My Custom Page View Variable', 'My Value']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'My Category', 'My Action']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
[...GA snippet insertion...]
```

This generates two `__utm.gif` requests to Google.  This would be okay except that the request with the `_trackEvent` information ALSO contains the `CustomVar` info, which leads me to believe that Google counts the pageview on BOTH requests.  I don't want to double count my page requests... so is Google smart enough to throw away the pageview info sent with the `_trackEvent` call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't double count page views but it is double counting your custom var. If you don't want that, reorder the pushes, make the trackpageview come first, then the custom var, then the event

Comment: Thanks!  For the benefit of other people, Google's documentation actually has this info and I somehow missed it:  http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html